# Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

on this code snippet, i am getting the error stated above as
'Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput'

```
  onFileSelected(event: any, user: any){
   this.crudservice.upload(event.target.files[0], `images/profile/${user.uid}`).pipe(
     concatMap(res = > this.crudservice.updateProfileData({res}))
    ).subscribe()
   }
```

more specifically this line:

```
res = > this.crudservice.updateProfileData({res})
```

I will leave this here for reference on the method being called:

```
    updateProfileData(profileData: any){
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    return of(user).pipe(
      concatMap(user =>{
        if(!user) throw new Error('Not Authenticated');
        return updateProfile(user,profileData)
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: You try removing the space between `= >`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the space between `= >` in `res = > this.crudservice.updateProfileData({res})`. The function operator cannot have a space between otherwise it's an assignment with a greater-then boolean operation.

The following should work:

```js
onFileSelected(event: any, user: any){
   this.crudservice.upload(event.target.files[0], `images/profile/${user.uid}`).pipe(
     // Fix here   v
     concatMap(res => this.crudservice.updateProfileData({res}))
   ).subscribe()
}
```

Comment: thanks heaps! its always those small things aye haha